# MediaElement seems to disable lock screen when playing a video

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml, mediaelement, lockscreen

I am working on an application that plays a video using the MediaElement component. Now, I would like that if the user is idle, the lock screen appears, as configured by the user in the Settings of the device.

If I don't play a video, the lock screen indeed appears. But, when a video is playing no lock screen appears. I cannot find any information on this.

Currently I set the idle detection modes like this:

```
PhoneApplicationService.Current.ApplicationIdleDetectionMode = IdleDetectionMode.Enabled;
PhoneApplicationService.Current.UserIdleDetectionMode = IdleDetectionMode.Enabled;
```

I am a bit lost now. The only solution I can think of is running a timer myself and stop the video playback after a certain time. (but there seems to be no API calls to receive the configured lock timeout.)

Any suggestions are welcome, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One workaround for you would be to enable running under the lockscreen. Then in the obscured even you could stop the mediaplayer. Not ideal, but it might serve your purposes.

Comment: The problem is that the lockscreen does not appear when a video is playing.

Comment: I thought it might if you enable running under the lockscreen, but perhaps not. Have you tried resetting the idle detections after you start the video playing? Might be worth a shot.